# While import file will have many row maybe more than 5000 rows

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

While import file will have many row maybe more than 5000 row, so I want  export files to cut 1-100 row to in 1 excel and then 101-201​ to another file and then  loop file until to 5000 row.

```
Sub test()
Sheet60.Range("A1:BX100").Copy
Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("D:\Implement\text.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step through the loop, I used Sheet60 because that is what you used in your code.

```
    Sub MakeWBs()
    Dim dr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, x As Long
    Dim Nsh As Worksheet

    dr = "C:\TestNewFolder"                      'change to your folder
    Set ws = Sheet60
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To LstRw Step 100             'step 100 next loop goes to 101 ect
            Set Nsh = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            Nsh.Name = x
            .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 99, 76)).Copy Nsh.Range("A1")
            Nsh.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=dr & "\" & Nsh.Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Nsh.Delete
        Next x
    End With

    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,  method 'Add'  of object 'sheets' failed

Comment: Ok, Thank you i add the path file to code.